# printing with QGIS/PostGIS

Tags: qgis, printing

I'm having a hard time printing a map within QGIS. For instance I did a 18x24 inch map printed on a 18x24 inch map. But the printed a map on a 9x12 inch printed on a 24x36 piece of paper. Why is it hard to print a big/wall map out in QGIS? Is there a step I'm missing?

Comment: We do it all the time... 34"x22", etc... are you setting your print composer page size correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are not setting your composer size correctly.  When printing, the QGIS Composer has 2 different places you need to set the page size, and they DO NOT affect the other.

1) Page Setup:  I'm guessing you set the page size using Composer > Page Setup.  This sets page size being sent to the printer.

2) Composition tab: In order to change the page size of the document workspace, change the "Page Size".  This is most easily done with the "Presets" pull-down menu.

To demonstrate why this might be helpful, imagine this scenario.  I am designing a large poster, but I just want to print a copy in my office to see how it would look.  I might set my Composition page size to ANSI E (34x44) but set my Page Setup to ANSI A (8.5x11) and send my poster to my letter sized printer for review.

For me personally, I prefer to export my composer map to a PDF file instead of sending directly to the printer. That way I can confirm my page size and/or use Adobe Acrobat to scale up/down automatically as needed, matching the page size in the printer.

Comment: Hey i'm still having an issue. i'm trying to print an 11 x 17 map on a 18 x 24 inch piece of paper. but it only prints half of what i want. it gets cut off.  Ok  what do i do? what do i set the composition size and the page setup size to ? thanks